# Code runs into an unexpected infinite while loop?

Tags: python

**Please take into account that I am doing this for homework, I don't want to use any built in methods, I am only working with what I've learnt, which is the find method**

I'm trying to count the amount fo words in a string, but it seems to run forever? I've even tried `sentence.find(" ", last_position) != -1:` as an if inside the while having it as `while True:`

```
def count_words(sentence):
    count = 0
    last_position = 0

    while sentence.find(" ", last_position) != -1:
        count += 1
        last_position = sentence.find(" ", last_position) + 1

    return count + 1 # +1 because essentially we're only count spaces, not words..
```

Comment: If a space was found at `last_position`, then searching again starting at that position is going to find the same space again, forever.  You need to add 1 when assigning the new value to `last_position`. (Putting a `print(last_position)` in the loop would have made this obvious - did that not even occur to you?)

Comment: I've updated my question to do `+1` when assigning last_position, it still results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you sure? What are you passing into the function?

Comment: This is equivalent to `sentence.count(" ") + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `find`, the `start` argument is interpreted as a slice argument. If you are not familiar with slices, `start` is included. Therefore, `find` searches the string *including* the index of the character that was just found. As a result of this, `find` repeatedly returns the same index, thus creating an infinite loop.

To fix this, as jasonharper mentioned, simply add 1:

```
last_position = sentence.find(" ", last_position) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves it. I seem to mess up indexes a lot, damn.

Answer (score 0):

Old school way with your existing code. See more about [find()](https://www.jquery-az.com/5-examples-python-string-find-search-string-contains-word/)

```
def count_words(sentence):
    count = 0
    last_position = sentence.find(" ", 0)  
    while last_position != -1:
        count += 1
        last_position+=1
        last_position = sentence.find(" ", last_position)

    return count+1

result = count_words('my name is always sunny')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug(use ipython):

```
In [2]: s = 'asdfasdf asdf asdf asd sdfa'
In [4]: def count_words(sentence):
   ...:     count = 0
   ...:     last_position = 0
   ...:
   ...:     while sentence.find(" ", last_position) != -1:
   ...:         count += 1
   ...:         print(f'count: {count}, position: {last_position}')
   ...:         last_position = sentence.find(" ", last_position)
   ...:         print(f'new position: {last_position}')
   ...:         if count > 4:
   ...:             break
   ...:     return count
   ...:

In [5]: count_words(s)
count: 1, position: 0
new position: 8
count: 2, position: 8
new position: 8
count: 3, position: 8
new position: 8
count: 4, position: 8
new position: 8
count: 5, position: 8
new position: 8
Out[5]: 5
```

See why:

```
In [6]: s.find?
Docstring:
S.find(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Return -1 on failure.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

Fixing:

```
In [7]: def count_words(sentence):
   ...:     count = 0
   ...:     last_position = 0
   ...:
   ...:     while sentence.find(" ", last_position) != -1:
   ...:         count += 1
   ...:         last_position = sentence.find(" ", last_position+1)
   ...:     return count
   ...:

In [8]: count_words(s)
Out[8]: 5
```